# Relationship between invertible matrices and exponential matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

Let $\mathbb{M}(n,\mathbb{F})$ be the set of all $n \times n$ matrices  over a field $\mathbb{F}$. I now take the subset comprising all matrices that are matrix exponentials of some other matrices

$$A=\exp (B)$$

The properties of the matrix exponential are such that all of these matrices are invertible

$$A A^{-1} = \exp (B) \exp(-B) = \exp(B-B)= \exp (0) = I$$

Is the subset of all invertible matrices the same as the subset of all matrices that can be expressed as exponentials?

Comment: You don't have to deal with the general case. You can consider $1 \times 1$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ and the exponential map agrees with the matrix exponential. This should answer your question!

Comment: some invertible matrices over real numbers have negative determinants while the determinant of a matrix exponential is always greater than zero. If the two sets are the same (perhaps you meant similar), then similar matrices should have the same determinant!

Comment: @OsamaGhani I don't see how it working for $1\times 1$ matrices, implies it works for $n\times n$ matrices?

Comment: On the contrary, it doesn't work for $1 \times 1$ matrices so there's your first counterexample. $[-1]$ is invertible but is not the exponential of any matrix (over $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: How do you define matrix exponential over an arbitrary field $\mathbb F$?